# Laravel Blade if is not working in blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

I want to show 'Applied' `li` when current login person already applied for a job. Showing all values instead of showing just else part. My code is given below

```
@foreach($applicant as $a)
   @if($a->is_applied == false)
       <li class="apply">
          <div class="applicant">
            <form method="post" action="{{ route('applicant.store',$postjob->id) }}">
               @csrf
               <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Apply</button>
            </form>
           </div>
        </li>
     @else
        <li><a class="disabled" href="">Applied</a></li>
     @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: You're `@foreach`ing through *all* applicants. You need to check if the current user applied.

Comment: Sir, I have tried this @if($a->Auth::user()->is_applied == true) But still not working. Can you please help me?

Comment: What do you get when you dump the value of `is_applied` for all the applicants?

Comment: You can try `@unless($a->is_applied)`

Comment: You can try with just @if(!($a->is_applied))

Comment: What's the error you're getting ? and what is the output of this `$a->is_applied`

Comment: It is actally `foreach` ing among all applicants

Comment: Just show me the output of this `$applicant` i will loop it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

When you save a **text string** in the database, in this case "true" or "false", and you test it against being **boolean** `true` or `false`, it will **always** return `true` because the text string is set. In other words, the text string is not empty — and therefore `true`.

So, if you would like to test the value (as a text string) to be 'true' or 'false', you must put the 'true' or 'false' between quotation marks, like so:

```
@if($a->is_applied == 'false')
//...
@endif
```

Comment: No. I saved data as Boolean value. I previously wrote the same way it did worked. there is no problem with 'false' or false.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
@if($a->is_applied)
     //...
@endif
```